# ¿Se puede hacer más de una clase en un mismo .java?

Tags: java, poo

soy principiante absoluto en java y estoy aprendiendo de forma autodidacta mediante w3school, concretamente la programación orientada a objetos.

He visto que si por ejemplo quiero hacer una clase y luego un main, tengo que poner dicho main dentro de otra clase por lo que necesito hacer dos ficheros .java, uno para la clase y otro para la que contiene el main. Mi pregunta es: es siempre necesario hacer un fichero.java por cada clase?

Seguro que es muy absurdo lo que pregunto, pero por algún lado se tiene que empezar a aprender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un archivo .java puede tener más de una clase. La única condición es que sólo debe haber una clase public con el mismo nombre del archivo.

Ejemplo. Main.java

```
  package test;

    //Clase principal
    public class Main{

       public Main(){
        System.out.println("Hola, mundo");
       }

       public static void main(String[] args){
          Main mainC = new Main();
          X my_x = new X();
          Y my_y = new Y();
          Z my_z = new Z();
       }
    }

//otras clases
    class X{
       public X(){
         System.out.println("Hola desde X");
       }
    }

    class Y{
       public Y(){
         System.out.println("Hola desde Y");
       }
    }

    class Z{
       public Z(){
         System.out.println("Hola desde Z");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo primero a tu pregunta, no es necesario SIEMPRE crear una archivo para cada clase.

En java las clases tienen 2 tipos de vibilidad posible: *public* y *package*. Las clases con visibilidad *public* serán visibles desde cualquier paquete y requieren ser escritas en una archivo .java con cuyo nombre sea el mismo que el de la clase.

```
public class Test {...}  ->  Test.java
```

Por el contrario, las clases con vivibilidad *package* pueden estar definidas en una archivo .java propio, cuyo nombre coincida con el de la clase o dentro de otro archivo .java perteneciente a otra clase.

```
// Notar la ausencia del public
class Otra {}  -> Otra.java o Test.java
```

Ahora, el método `main` puede estar definido en cualquier clase, por lo que si tienes un programa que solo consta de una clase, no estás obligado a crear otra solamente para incluir este método.